# A question about "General and Particular Solutions" (I guess) which I'm not sure what they mean

Tags: homogeneous-equation

We have a $3\times 6$ matrix $A$ with rank $3$ (this is all the information we have, no matrix given). Here comes the questions:

What is the number of free variables in the solution to the system $Ax = 0$?

(Well, it must be 3. Although I think I know the answer, I didn't exclude this part of question because I think there must be somebody who can explain better.)

For a given $b$, are we guaranteed to have a solution to $Ax = b$?

If we have a solution, what is the dimension of the solution space?

(The asker wants us to explain without using an example.)

Comment: Ponder on the definitions of *rank* and *free variable* and I think you have your answer.

Comment: Thank you for your comment but I still have no idea how to explain without giving an example. :)

Comment: So give an example.  That might help you understand what's going on in general.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to think that since the question requires a solution without examples, you may not use examples to solve the problem.  Not true! Playing with an example can give you the insight to understand the concept behind the problem.

The simplest $3 \times 6$ matrix that I can think of with rank 3 is
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$
Then any vector of the form $x_0 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & x_4 & x_5 & x_6 \end{bmatrix}^T$ is a solution to $Ax=0$.  We see three free variables.

Given a vector $b$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, the system $Ax=b$ has a solution if $b$ can be written as a linear combination of columns of $A$.  If $b = \begin{bmatrix} c_1 & c_2 & c_3 \end{bmatrix}^T$, then $x_p = \begin{bmatrix} c_1 & c_2 & c_3 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}^T$ will do (try it).  In fact, $\begin{bmatrix} c_1 & c_2 & c_3 & x_4 & x_5 & x_6 \end{bmatrix}^T$ is also a solution for any values of $x_4$, $x_5$, and $x_6$.  Therefore, solution space is an affine space of dimension 3.

In general, the *rank-nullity theorem* says the rank plus the nullity (dimension of the kernel) of a matrix equals the number of columns in the matrix.  If $A$ is of rank 3, its columns span $\mathbb{R}^3$.  Finally, if $x_0$ is a solution to $Ax=0$, and $x_p$ is a solution to $Ax=b$, what can you say about $x_0 + x_p$?

PS In your question title you ask about the terms *general* and *particular solution*.  In a system of equations of the form $Ax=b$, a particular solution is a single solution, and the general solution is a description of all solutions.  What this problem is illustrating is that once one particular solution is found, any solution can be found by adding to the particular solution a solution to the homogeneous system $Ax=0$.

Comment: In order to turn your nice solution to a without-using-example solution, I said null space of A is the same as that of the null space of the reduced row echelon form of A. rref(A) is something like $\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&a&b&c\\0&1&0&d&e&f\\0&0&1&g&h&i\end{bmatrix}$. Multiplied it by $[x_{1} x_{2} x_{3} x_{4} x_{5} x_{6}]^{T}$ and got the zero vector. So my nullspace is the set of vectors $[x_{1} x_{2} x_{3} x_{4} x_{5} x_{6}]^{T} = x_{4}[-a -d -g 1 0 0]^{T} + x_{5}[-b -e -h 0 1 0]^{T} + x_{6}[-c -f -i 0 0 1]^{T}$.

Comment: If $b = \begin{bmatrix}k_1 & k_2 & k_3\end{bmatrix}^T$

Comment: Then $\begin{bmatrix} k_{1} & k_{2} & k_{3} & 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}^T$ is a solution for rref(A)x = b.

Comment: Is it also a solution for Ax = b?

Comment: @Kerem: that's a good question.  What is the relationship between a matrix and its rref?  But maybe the solution need not be constructive.  If the columns of $A$ span $\mathbb{R}^3$, any $b$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ can be written as a linear combination of the columns of $A$.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "constructive" and I'm not sure what you're driving at. :)